# ffmpeg video to gif with custom palette

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

How do I amend to following command so I can use a custom palette called **palette.png**

`ffmpeg -i movie.mov -filter_complex "[0:v] fps=12,scale=600:-1,split [a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse" movie.gif`

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your palette image is well-formed (width x height = 256), use

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mov -i palette.png -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=12,scale=600:-1[v];[v][1]paletteuse" movie.gif
```